# how can I install wine 1.4 on ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, wine

When I try to install wine 1.4 i get this errors:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

wine1.4: PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.15.7.2~) pero 1.16.10ubuntu1 is to be installed
         Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) pero 2.17-0ubuntu5 is to be installed
         Depends: wine1.4-amd64 (= 1.4.1-0ubuntu5) but 1.4.1-0ubuntu5 is to be installed
         Depends: wine1.4-i386 (= 1.4.1-0ubuntu5) but it is not going to be installed
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: What are the steps you took prior to this error? What exact command did you use (or what tool did you use)? Do you have some extra repositories added to your system? Please provide the output of `apt-cache policy wine1.4` run from a terminal. Include all this new information in your question by *editing* it.

Comment: This question might help: http://askubuntu.com/q/140246/8973

Answer (score 2):

I recommend [PlayOnLinux [image: Install playonlinux]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/playonlinux). It's a user friendly version of Wine. You can install it from Ubuntu software Center.

Comment: This does not answer the question, but is merely a (personal, subjective) recommendation for an alternative to Wine.

Comment: @gertvdijk Sorry, I will post this sort of things in a comment from now on.

Comment: I understand what @gertvdijk is saying, but PlayOnLinux does allow you to install Wine Bottles of various versions very easily and could be a solution to the OP's problem.

Comment: Also, it looks like PlayOnLinux isn't available for 13.04 at thist ime. See https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/playonlinux

Answer (score 1):

To install Wine in Ubuntu 13.04, just click the correct architecture below

[**Install Wine 32bit Version 1.4.1** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/wine1.4-i386/)

[**Install Wine 64bit Version 1.4** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/wine1.4-amd64/)

Note: Wine 64bit provides support for loading 64-bit x86 Windows applications, its listed for Ubuntu 12.10, I think the it will probably work with 13.04, but I'm not 100% sure, and may not work with 13.04.

Answer (score -2):

Add this PPA to your ubuntu software centre.
https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ppa

Comment: Why? Wine 1.4 is in the main repositories! http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/wine1.4 No need for a PPA here.